# JavaFX: Exposing ObjectProperty members instead of getter/setter?

Tags: java, oop, javafx, properties, encapsulation

I have looked into som classes and their declarations and I come arcross a new way of encapsulation which make an ordinary getter/setter way of reaching the an instance variable look like barbarism...

Inside `javafx.scene.Scene` search for camera, an object of `javafx.scene.Camera` and look at it's encapsulation.

You can also see it here on [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/scene/Scene.java/?v=source)

*This down below is from the JavaFX Scene class:*

```
private ObjectProperty<Camera> camera;

public final void setCamera(Camera value) {
    cameraProperty().set(value);
}

public final Camera getCamera() {
    return camera == null ? null : camera.get();
}

public final ObjectProperty<Camera> cameraProperty() {
    if (camera == null) {
        camera = new ObjectPropertyBase<Camera>() {
            Camera oldCamera = null;

            @Override
            protected void invalidated() {
                Camera _value = get();
                if (_value != null) {
                    if (_value instanceof PerspectiveCamera
                            && !Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D)) {
                        String logname = Scene.class.getName();
                        PlatformLogger.getLogger(logname).warning("System can't support "
                                + "ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D");
                    }
                    // Illegal value if it belongs to other scene or any subscene
                    if ((_value.getScene() != null && _value.getScene() != Scene.this)
                            || _value.getSubScene() != null) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(_value
                                + "is already part of other scene or subscene");
                    }
                    // throws exception if the camera already has a different owner
                    _value.setOwnerScene(Scene.this);
                    _value.setViewWidth(getWidth());
                    _value.setViewHeight(getHeight());
                }
                if (oldCamera != null && oldCamera != _value) {
                    oldCamera.setOwnerScene(null);
                }
                oldCamera = _value;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getBean() {
                return Scene.this;
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "camera";
            }
        };
    }
    return camera;
}

Camera getEffectiveCamera() {
    final Camera cam = getCamera();
    if (cam == null
            || (cam instanceof PerspectiveCamera
            && !Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D))) {
        if (defaultCamera == null) {
            defaultCamera = new ParallelCamera();
            defaultCamera.setOwnerScene(this);
            defaultCamera.setViewWidth(getWidth());
            defaultCamera.setViewHeight(getHeight());
        }
        return defaultCamera;
    }

    return cam;
}
```

When should I use this methodology of putting the instance variable inside `javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty<T>` and add extra abstractation layers, how or in what would way would it be useful?

*Notice: I am aware of the possibilty of adding listeners to properties - but are there other reasons?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can see here is one kind of implementation of lazy initialization.

The property `camera` does not get initialized until it is not really being get.

No "extra abstraction layer" is present in the snippet: `cameraProperty()` exposes the `camera` inner propery (and initializes it on the very first call). The accessor and the mutator methods are simple shortcuts to `cameraProperty().get()` and `cameraProperty().set(...)`.

The same is explained in this answer:
[Exposing properties for binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349849/exposing-properties-for-binding/39350046#39350046)

Comment: Does it not also allow for separation between the first set method call (initialization) and later use of set method (changing of instance variables) - so that they can be coded differently? It should mean you could initialize all instance variable seperately and uniquely (rather than having a generalized init method). And thank you, delaying initialization makes sense and it is good to now know the term "lazy initialization"!

Comment: The only difference is (beside that `camera` is a "special" property - that means it is not initialized as a `new SimpleObjectProperty()`)  is that camera is not initialized in the costructor, but -lazily- only if that property is requested for any usage.

Comment: If I still would put `cameraProperty.set(value)` in the contructor and we three such methods (setting a camera1, camera2 and camera3 in total). I am initializing them at the same time - but I can do it differently (inside) `cameraProperty` for each camera. I think that is another benfit of putting an `ObjectProperty` around the instance variable. The alternative would to have seperate init methods - it does not seem to be as appealing I think

Comment: There is no "wrapping". `cameraProperty()` returns the member variable `camera`. `cameraProperty()` is a method.

Comment: What if you just check if the instance variable is null. The `ObjectPropery<>`  is not required to do a lazy initialization.

Comment: The `ObjectPropery<>` is needed if you want the member to be observable. Without wrapping the `Camera` member into a property, you cannot attach listeners to notice you when the camera was exhanged or you cannot use it in a binding. Without the `ObjectProperty<>` wrapping, you would normally an accessor and a mutator method for that field, and lazy initialization could be implemented for example in the getter.